# AutoCad EndPlot event firing too soon in (C#, API)

Tags: c#, api, events, autocad

i am leveraging the AutoCad API's to do the following...

1] open autocad
2] load a document
3] print the document
4] close autocad

All this is working fine except for the fact that autocad is closing too quickly before the document has finished spooling off. To get around this i have subscribed to the EndPlot event (printing has finished) and then tried to get my app to close.

The problem i am having is that endPlot fires WELL BEFORE the document has spooled off to the printer - and so i get no output.

Does anyone have any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that background plotting is disabled.
You can do that either in options or set BACKGROUNDPLOT to 0 from the command prompt.

Comment: Hi, i have tried what you suggested but the event is still fired at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try en-queuing a 2nd plot to a null device and wait for that to finish (or start, as it seems).

Have you looked into simply waiting for the bool return value of object.PlotToDevice [plotConfig] ?